# Since which Android version is "drawable-nodpi" supported?

Tags: android, android-version, android-drawable

Since **which Android version** is **"drawable-nodpi"** supported? Is it safe to put images in **"res/drawable-nodpi"** and expect them to work in all android version from at least since **2.0(Eclair)** and up?

Comment: Not sure, but you can always use the /raw folder and load a bitmap from there to be sure it works and doesn't get scaled

Comment: I am not sure but its Android 1.6+.

Comment: Oh, if it works since 1.6 them I am safe! :-)

Comment: @Stefan: Yeah but, its not that seamless when using in layout.xml files, right? Actually I am using the "drawable-nodpi/my_image_big.png" as an original for my "drawable-xlarge-mdpi/my_image.xml". So, I choose "drawable-nodpi", because I dont want android to scale them. :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [this document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) there is no "Added in API level X" below nodpi. So it must be supported by all platforms.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. I couldn't find the added since mention anywhere in the documentation. Thanks!